# How can I hover over an image and get the coordinates of the position where my mouse is present

Tags: javascript, python, image, web, flappy-bird-clone

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ArCFchlTq4&t=486s) tutorial on youtube regarding making a flappy bird game..

The guy teaching has used [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOzXK.png) image in the project.

I want to use different parts of this image separately..
How can I make sure that i hover over some point in the image and i get to know the coordinates of that point(with respect to the image and not with respect to my screen)? Can i make this happen with some code editor like the one the youtube guy is using in his tutorial..Or is there any javascript or python script through which i can make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem before and the module I used was called pyautogui. To use it, first run the pip command like this:
`python -m pip install pyautogui` and then just import it. To get the mouse position use `pyautogui.position()`. If you want more information, [this](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) is the link to the official website for pyautogui which may have some other tools to help you during your project

Comment: i thought of this before but pyautogui.position() will give the position of that point with respect to entire screen and not with respect to that image